# Solving $6\theta+6\sin(2\theta)=3\sqrt3+\pi$, and $15\theta+4\cos(\theta)=5\pi$ (two separate equations, not a system)

Tags: trigonometry

Please help me solve these two *separate* trigonometry equations (not a system).

> $$6\theta+6\sin(2\theta)=3\sqrt3+\pi \tag{1}$$
>   $$15\theta+4\cos(\theta)=5\pi \tag{2}$$

To know the answers is my great pleasure

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best promote your understanding, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Comments are easily overlooked, so please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3452181/edit) to add details.

Comment: Dude you should show your approach

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, the equation $$6\theta+6\sin(2\theta)=3\sqrt3+\pi$$ has the solution $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}6$.  This is easily verified by substitution.

Not sure if there is an algebraic solution to the second one.

Comment: I just found a mistake in my second equation. that would be $$15θ+12cos(θ)=5\pi$$

Comment: @aminabzz There still does not appear to be an algebraic solution.  How do you think I was able to come to the solution for the first question _by inspection_?  (Hint:  the two "related" components on either side have to be equal).